# Is there a XMPP method to get the number of rooms already present on a server?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, chatroom

Is there any predefined method in XMPP to get the number of rooms already present on the openfire server. I have made a thorough search but I am unable to get the good and working answer.

Please let me know how can I get the rooms available on openfire server ( already created ).

The code

```
boolean supports = MultiUserChat.isServiceEnabled(conn, "user3@host.org/Smack");
```

is returning a NUll pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getHostedRooms](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#getHostedRooms%28org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection,%20java.lang.String%29) method of MultiUserChat class of Smack API.

> `public static Collection<HostedRoom> getHostedRooms(Connection`
>   `connection, String serviceName)  throws XMPPException`

This will return collection of all public [rooms](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/HostedRoom.html) on server. And before this check if user supports MUC or not by

```
boolean supports = MultiUserChat.isServiceEnabled(conn, "user3@host.org/Smack");
```

More information on this can be found on [smack api guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. I am checking it and will let you know if it works.
Meanwhile can you please help me in this matter?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028384/xmpp-room-invitation

Comment: I am getting a nullpointer exception on isServiceEnabled line?

Comment: @GauravArora instead of "user3@host.org/Smack" you have to pass your user id. Also make sure your connection is not null. Call this after login is successful.

Comment: Its obvious dear I am doing it with my own id bro :(

Comment: Then most possible cause is that your connection object is null. Check for it.

Comment: debugger is not responding on that line. I have checked the connection. It is working fine at that place. Moreover while debugging it says : -supports cannot be resolved to a variable.Dats it.

Comment: if you are sure your server has rooms then you can skip that line and directly try to get the rooms.